# How do i change the input shape of a pytorch resnet50 model before training to 224, 224, 3 from 3, 224, 224

Tags: flutter, machine-learning, pytorch, tensorflow-lite, image-classification

How do i change the input shape of the pytorch resnet50 model before training on my dataset

I faced an error when i converted the trained model to .tflite format to use in a flutter app, which basically wanted me to change the input tensor of my model to 1, 224, 224, 3 from 1, 3, 224, 224.

Answer (score 1):

Permute the axes of your tensor:

```
x = x.permute(0,3,1,2)
```

Comment: I want to modify the resnet50 model itself. This solution seems to change the dimension of the input tensor rather.

Comment: In Pytorch, layers cannot take channel last tensors and operate on channel first tensors instead.